# Access Data from ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, angularjs-ng-repeat

i would like to use templates for a NetBanking app. 
Therefore i constructed a basic service to get Objects filled with some Names and IBAN (unique key for banking transactions) in my service.js:

```
    .factory('templateData', function(){
  var savedTemplates = [
      {name:"Adam Müller", iban:"AT29100020003000",img:"adam"},
      {name:"Ben Streicher",iban:"AT34900080007000",img:"ben"},
      {name:"Max Krossmann",iban:"AT23400050006000",img:"max"}
  ];

  var getTemplates = function(){
    return savedTemplates;
  };

  return {
    getTemplates:getTemplates,
  };


})
```

The controller saves this data via the .getTemplates() statement in a variable and the template view accesses mentioned variable with ng-repeat.
template.hmtl:

```
<div class="list" ng-model="chosentemplate">
<a

      class="item item-thumbnail-left"
      ng-repeat="template in Templatelist">
    <img src="img/{{template.img}}.jpg">

    <h2><b>{{template.name}}</b></h2>
    <button 
            style="float: right;"
            class="button button-positive pull-right"
            ng-click="onTemplateClick(chosentemplate.iban)"
            ui-sref="tab.transactions">Vorlage auswählen</button>
    <p ><b>IBAN</b> {{template.iban}}</p>
</a>
```

Now, I'd like to save the chosen object in the service to use it later when filling it into the transactions form. 
I'm struggling to access the used data from ng-repeat, when the button is clicked.
Some weeks ago i've done something quite similar, but just one child element of the object. I could access it with the equivalent to chosentemplate.name.

I would be very grateful for any suggestions!

Answer (score 2):

You are iterating the Templatelist with the template variable.
So, simply use :

```
 ng-click="onTemplateClick(template.iban)"
```

Comment: I tried that and wrote function in my service called onTemplateClick(item) with a console.log inside the function.
Unfortunately I never received an answer, when I clicked one of the buttons. 
Maybe there's a bigger mistake?